# Output age from year vaule and then increase by 1 every year javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, calculator

I have a custom field vaule in WordPress. This field is for the year of birth,
for example 1980. I would like to convert this year to display the age of (in the example) 33.

Furthermore, I would like to increase this number once every year. So next year, the age till be 34.

Is this possible to do with javascript?

Best regards,
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
function getAge(yearOfBirth) {
  return (new Date()).getFullYear() - yearOfBirth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just get the current date with JS, and substract the base year from it:

```
var base_year = 1980; //get this from DB

var today = new Date(); 
var current_year = today.getFullYear(); //2014 

alert (current_year - base_year); // = 34
```